# Which type of UK supermarket rice is closest to Philippine rice?

Tags: rice, asian-cuisine

I have visted the Philippines twice and had many delicious dishes served with the most amazing slightly-sticky rice.

Which type/variety of rice, which is readily available in UK supermarkets, is closest is terms of grain size, texture and fragrance? I have tried authentic Thai Jasmine rice which is delicious but much more fragrant. Long grain rice is nothing like it.

I've looked online and haven't been able to find any varieties that I recognise. I accept that I probably won't be able to find exactly the same variety so I'm looking for the closest match. There aren't any asian food markets/stores near me but it could be an option if nothing else is similar.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I think you want Dinorado  rice by farm boy. A 100% Philippine upland  rice.  I do not see a way to export it threw farm boy. Brand we buy. or maybe Sinadaomeng by Harvistor. Again I see no way to export it from them.  Sounds like you want Dinorado to me if this helps.

Comment: Found a way to do this. Go to Lazada Philippines. [ on line shopping] There you can order rice. Sinadomeng &some others. Have that shipped to you or to Germany to reship to you. Shipping will not be cheap.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is slightly sticky rice, you can mix glutinous(sweet) rice with plain rice in different ratios to get the right blend of stickiness you are looking for.

Short grain rice also tends to be more sticky, chewy, and denser. So go with short grain rice if you remember the rice being more dense and chewy.